React-Native Hooks delay causes Swipeable Table on Realm to Fail
I am trying to create a swipeable table with React-Native using a Realm database.  The question more reduces down to the timing of the hook accessing the underlying Realm table.  In the below code, i label 3 console.log statements A, B, C & D.  A & C both produce expected output of an array of objects representing the tables.  However, B is empty.  D does appear to be reached.  But using C's object in the return statement yields an error that it is 'undefined'.  It appears I need a "sooner" hook.  I have tried many things unsuccessfully to delay the return statement until the table object is populated.  In other instances in my code, I am able to render strings it appears but not objects.  However, I want the CRUD utilities I think may come available with a React-Table without having to write such code myself.  I have been working on a custom hook and another approach with React-Query, but had hoped for a bit more direction if possible.
My question, can I make this approach work or is there a better solution to render a CRUD-enabled table on my device.
  const SwipeableTable = ({ tables }: SwipeableTableProps) => {
  console.log('SwipeableTable props:', tables); //Log A
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(() => {
    if (tables && tables.length > 0) {
      return tables[0].data;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  });
  console.log('tableData:', tableData); //Log B
  const tableData2 = tables.map(table => table.data.flat())
 console.log('tableData2:', tableData2); //Log C
  const handleSwipeEnd = (index: number) => {
    console.log(`Swiped row at index ${index}`);
    console.log(`tableData at index ${index}:`, tableData[index]);
  };

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {tableData.map((table: unknown, index: React.Key | null | undefined) => {
      console.log('tableData item:', table); // Log D
      return (
        <SwipeableList key={index}>
          <SwipeableListItem
            swipeStartThreshold={0.1}
            onSwipeEnd={() => handleSwipeEnd(Number(index))}
          >
            <TableComponent table={table} />
          </SwipeableListItem>
        </SwipeableList>
      );
    })}
  </View>
);
};


Just be aware that all these console logs are unintentional side-effects, so there's no real correlation between what the logs output and the React component lifecycle. Please [edit] to clarify what the actual issue or problem is that you need help with.
